# Scrolling slows down From Top To Middle

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I have a Blogger blog and the scroll slows down from the top to approximately 300px.
You can take a look at the blog, [here](http://lejournalsn.blogspot.sn/).

What code is causing this?

Comment: I'm not seeing any speed difference from top to bottom

Comment: Please include the code you have problem with to avoid linkrot. The page you linked is very very laggy, and that may be your issue.

Comment: No thank you ! It was the body background image which was too big ! I changed it